# Cannot install Ubuntu 20.04 "SGX disabled by BIOS"

Tags: ubuntu, intel, ubuntu-20.04, bios, sgx

I am trying to boot Ubuntu 20.04 on ASUS® VivoBook x507ua but I am getting the following error message after choosing bootable USB driver

```
[    0.108692] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS
Unable to find a medium container a life file system
Attempt interactive netboot from a URL?
yes no (default yes): _
```

[photograph of above text rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTzIa.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

From what I see here, there should be no relation between SGX and installing ubuntu. The error you get might be because of a faulty installation medium.

You can still, however, enable SGX in your BIOS. But again, I really don't think this message and the error that follows are related.