# Sgx disable by bios Ubuntu acpi error 22.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, sgx

enter image description here[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4I5Mz.jpg)

Got error when booting up my laptop if any suggestions to remove these error glad to know

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72685814/cannot-install-ubuntu-20-04-sgx-disabled-by-bios

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406760/sgx-disabled-by-bios-in-ubuntu-22-04

Answer (score 0):

My ASUS laptop faced same issue and no solutions worked in my case.
Unfortunately, I had to reinstall Ubuntu 22.04 from bootable USB.
As long as you **don't check Format box** on installing partition selection, personal files will be kept under newly installed Ubuntu environment.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you have dual booted ubuntu and windows. If this is the case you might have acpi off in grub. Try this:

1. Start your pc and get to grub screen to select between windows and ubuntu
2. Press down/up to get to ubuntu line and press letter 'e' on keyboard.
3. Look "quiet splash acpi=off" line.
4. If you do not have "acpi=off", please disregard. If you do go to next step.
5. Remove "acpi=off", and press ctrl + x
6. Once you are booted into ubuntu open a terminal and type "sudo vim /etc/default/grub".
7. Look for GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off"
8. Once again remove acpi=off. Hit esc, then :, then type wq, and hit enter.
9. sudo update-grub

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same error on Acer SF-3125 52 series while running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS in dual boot with Windows 10.

Most online suggestions recommended enabling SGX in the BIOS settings. However, I couldn't proceed with that approach as there was no SGX option available in the BIOS.

Here is my workaround:

1. In the Windows OS, follow the steps outlined on this site to activate SGX: [Intel SGX Activation Guide](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000058952/software/intel-security-products.html).
2. After following the instructions, reboot your system.

This successfully resolved the issue for me.